# Worst case time complexity for recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity

```
int memo[101][101];  
int findMinPath(vector<vector<int> >& V, int r, int c) {  
  int R = V.size();  
  int C = V[0].size();  
  if (r >= R || c >= C) return 100000000; // Infinity  
  if (r == R - 1 && c == C - 1) return 0;  
  if (memo[r][c] != -1) return memo[r][c];  
  memo[r][c] =  V[r][c] + min(findMinPath(V, r + 1, c), findMinPath(V, r, c + 1));  
  return memo[r][c];  
}  

Callsite :   
memset(memo, -1, sizeof(memo));  
findMinPath(V, 0, 0);
```

In the above code, what will be the worst case time complexity?.I understand that every function will call other functions atmost one time, but I am not clear with the calculation of the time complexity.

Comment: You might want to add a language tag (although I'm not sure it will make a difference to the complexity).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but semantically your `memset` is wrong. It will set all *bytes* of of `memo` to `-1`. Using [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) would be a better choice. Or why not use `std::vector` for `memo` as well? Then you could initialize it when defining the variable.

Comment: My goal is not to make a perfect code here. I am interested in the time complexity.

Comment: As for your problem, you can call `findMinPath` recursively *twice* in each call. So the complexity can be exponential.

Comment: It would have been exponential if I was not storing the result of function calls in memo array (2^(r+c)) . Here every function is called atmost one time. So , time complexity cannot be exponential in this case.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour when the input matrix has a dimension above 101. Take @Someprogrammerdude's advice and use a vector<vector<int>> for the memoisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memoisation is the key here.  Normally this would have exponential growth, but because you never perform additional recursive steps if the result is previously computed in `memo`, then it is reduced to the number of elements in `memo` as a worst case.  i.e. **O( 101 x 101 )**

Comment: So in terms of R and C , the worst case complexity will be O(R*C) ?

Comment: Yes, if every vector inside `V` is of length `C`.  But you did not leave any clues about whether or not that is true.

Comment: Technically as written, this is O(1), as `101 * 101` doesn't depend on the column or row counts.